# Having Python Files in an R package- Where do I put it?

Tags: python, r, r-package, reticulate, file-structure

I am working on a R package and for various reasons I need to write some code in Python.

For my current workflow I have the various scripts sitting in the root directory which I run in my various R codes with `reticulate::py_run_file()` followed by `reticulate::py$my_function()` (not ideal, I know).

So my question is:

**Where do I place my Python files when developing an R package?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to put them under `inst/python`. The [spacyr](https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr/tree/master/inst/python) package has python files there for example.

Another option is the `exec/` directory.

To quote from [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/misc.html):

> exec/: for executable scripts. Unlike files placed in other
> directories, files in exec/ are automatically flagged as executable.
> Empirically, to the extent that R packages are shipping scripts for
> external interpreters, the inst/ directory seems to be the preferred
> location these days.